# Button: Active using JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Trying to make a simple button to be in an active, different style when it is clicked on. I am using HTML to lay out the button, CSS for styling, and hoping to use a bit of JavaScript to do so.

After looking around SO and finding there are many different ways such as using Checkbox to make a button by pure CSS, or jQuery, or JavaScript, I feel that JavaScript is the most close way that I am looking at.

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1">Details</button>
```

CSS

```
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 70px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.btn:active {
  background: #cecece;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active')
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/w5h6rffo/

**Additional Note**
Feature goal is to have multiple buttons with the same class but each button calling to a different functions. I have the calling of the functions working, just not the button staying at ***an active state when it is first pressed, then at an inactive state when it is pressed again***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close to doing it right, the mechanism you built using a check to see if your element has the `active` class is nice but jQuery has a [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function which allows you to just write the following:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Then in your CSS, instead of styling the pseudo `:active` you'll use a classname instead like this:

```
.btn.active {
    background: #cecece;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

<strike>You'll also want to remove the `:active` selector from your CSS altogether since you won't be needing it anymore</strike> :)

As [dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq) pointed out there is a certain value in retaining the `:active` pseudo selector:

> I just think that active state (:active) for the control elements is
> important. For example, without it button will look the same if it is
> pressed but not clicked (mouseout before mouseup). UX is slightly
> better with :active. <strike>But maybe I'm too picky</strike>

For this reason you might want to modify the selector to be:

```
.btn.active, .btn:active {
    background: #cecece;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

As this will affect both the '.active' and the ':active' state.

Comment: *"You'll also want to remove the :active selector from your CSS alltogether since you won't be needing it anymore"*. No, it **is** still needed actually. Both .active and :active are needed. Effect is nicer.

Comment: d'oh! your answer beat mine by about 40 seconds.

Comment: @dfsq It is absolutely not needed, it will only differ when the user uses tab-based navigation instead of a mouse, as for the effect, it will not look nicer but rather **exactly the same** so *yes, you __can__ remove the `:active` selector*

Comment: *"but rather exactly the same so yes"* - of course not. There is actually significant difference with and *without* :active pseudo-class. But nevermind. Of course you *can* remove it, but it makes a difference.

Comment: @dfsq point me to any page that shows me this and I will gladly admit that I am wrong

Comment: I have updated my jsFiddle. When the button is pressed, it does not stay in an active stage when the click is removed. http://jsfiddle.net/w5h6rffo/1/

Comment: You are not wrong, you are right saying that it can be removed without problems. I just think that active state (:active) for the control elements is important. For example, without it button will look the same if it is pressed but not clicked (mouseout before mouseup). UX is *slightly* better with :active. But maybe I'm too picky.

Comment: @dfsq then I understood you wrong, I will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: My apology. I have written 
'<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>' 
in my html file but I guess it was not calling(?) , I will check  !! thank you

Comment: May I ask a quick question? when I write the Javascript / Jquery code inside the HTML file, it works, but when i remove it from the HTML file and rather, add it onto the JavaScript, js file, it does not work. At the beginning of HTML, I am pointing to the file location correctly...

Comment: You need to worry about wether the *DOM is loaded* if you include your file before the elements exist it will not work, use jQueries `$(document).ready(function() {})` or the shorthand `$(function() {})` for that. If you have content loaded through AJAX that's a different thing too and you'll want to look for *event delegation*

Answer (score 4):

You could use classList.toggle() in conjunction to a .active class.

So your code would look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .btn {
            background: #3498db;
            border-radius: 0px;
            font-family: Arial;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
            text-decoration: none;
            height: 30px;
            width: 70px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            display: block;
        }

        .btn.active {
            background: #cecece;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn">Button</button>
        <button class="btn">Button</button>
        <button class="btn">Button</button>
        <button class="btn">Button</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        function toggleActiveState() {
            this.classList.toggle('active');
        }
        var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
        [].forEach.call(btns, function(btn) {
          btn.addEventListener('click', toggleActiveState, false);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

This aproach would work for a infinite number of buttons.

Comment: the OP is using jQuery, this only adds an active state **every time** it gets clicked and doesn't remove it when clicked again either.

Comment: Now it does toggle the class. And why would you prefer to use jQuery when vanilla JavaScript does the job?

Comment: Since the OP is already using jQuery for one, the second is that he is also already using the unobstructing approach which makes your HTML much more flexible than what you have. Say you have alot more elements you'd have to add the onclick on the server side or in the HTML, if you do this in JS you don't have to do this since the handler just listens to a class that it has to bind to.

Comment: I'm sorry to dissapoint you but it's not a race, the fact is that the OP is using *jquery* and *jquery* just has benefits so that you don't have to **worry** about writing plain JS like making it cross browser compatible. Your solution will work perfect but chances are more likely that it will glitch and it's writing more code (jQuery slogan: **write less, do more**)

Answer (score 4):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active What's happening now is that it's working just fine :-) but what you're asking it to do and what you want it to do are not the same thing.

I think you need to fix your css and define `active` as a class rather than a pseudo-class (untested, but here goes):

```
.active {
   background: #cecece;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is the same answer that Sidney has written below (and his was faster), I will still press the upvote, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This is pure **HTML**, **CSS** and **JS** Approach! I hope it will be helpful!!

```js
const room  = document.querySelector('.chat-rooms');
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn'); 

room.addEventListener('click', e => {

 btns.forEach(btn => {

    if(btn.getAttribute('id') === e.target.getAttribute('id'))
      btn.classList.add('active');
    else
      btn.classList.remove('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.active,.btn:hover{ background-color:rgb(123, 255, 0); }
```

```html
    <div class="chat-rooms">
      <button class="btn" id="general">#general</button>
      <button class="btn" id="gaming">#gaming</button>
      <button class="btn" id="music">#music</button>
      <button class="btn" id="coding">#coding</button>
    </div>
```

```
[You can refer my code pen snippet to test!] 
> > https://codepen.io/blueKode/pen/abdZmYJ
```

Comment: codepen works, but could you try to demonstrate this in Stack Overflows native code snippet?

Comment: Rahul I have post the code snippet hope it will be helpful;!

Comment: Looks good. I had already upvoted your answer, so there is no more I can do. Since this is an old question this may be under the radar.
(My task was to help you how to use tools to improve your answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's **toggleClass( className )** function.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```
<script>
    $("button.btn").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
</script>

<style>
    .active{
      // your active style
     }
<style>
```